# Gnuplotting multi-plot data without a textfile

Tags: gnuplot, inlining

I've just read [Gnuplotting data without a textfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318228/gnuplotting-data-without-a-textfile), and I want to do the same thing, but with a "multi-plot". I currently have:

```
plot 'data.csv' using 1:3:2:6:5:7:xticlabels(8) with candlesticks title 'Quartiles' whiskerbars, \
  ''         using 1:4:4:4:4:4 with candlesticks lt -1 notitle
```

and I want to inline the data in `data.csv`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy enough:

```
set multiplot layout 1,2
plot '-' u 1:2
1 2
2 3
3 4  
e

plot '-' u 1:2
2 3
3 4
4 5
e
```

Note that inline data is not really particularly happy with the `''` pseudofile.  You would actually need to include your entire data again at that point.  So, If you want 2 traces on the same subplot of a multiplot:

```
set multiplot layout 1,2
plot '-' u 1:2, '-' u 1:3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
e
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
e

plot '-' u 1:($2*$3)
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
e
```

This ends up being the same thing as if you had a datafile `data.txt`:

```
#data.txt
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and plotted it with this (much simpler) script:

```
set multiplot layout 1,2
plot 'data.txt' u 1:2, '' u 1:3
plot '' u 1:($2*$3)
```

Comment: So, there's absolutely no alternative to having the data inlined (at least) twice?

Comment: I don't really think so.  You *might* be able to accomplish something with the `volatile` keyword and using `refresh`, but I sort of doubt it.

Comment: Congrats to the gnuplot gold badge :)